# Navigation Indicator for Current Page and Sub-Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, navigation

I have seen similar questions answered but I cannot find exactly my problem and I can't work out how to change the others to make them fit.

I am writing a simple rails 3 app that has 2 main sections. One called Students and one called iConnects with multiple pages for each. I have a simple navigation bar to allow navigation to either by navigating to the first record of either of these sections when clicked. This click also sets a class which has a colour set on it in CSS to indicate which section you are on. This however only works if you click that link once. If you navigate to any of the sub-pages e.g. students/2 the class is obviously not present there and there is no visual indication.

My question is how do I have a persistent class added to the navigation to indicate whether the user is on either students or iConnects?

I have a separate partial in my shared which I am pulling in with this code..

```
<div id="section_navigation">
    <%= link_to 'iConnect', @iconnects.first, :class => current_page?(@iconnects.first) ? "current" : "" %>
    <%= link_to 'Students', @pages.first, :class => current_page?(@pages.first) ? "current" : "" %>
</div>
```

And from my students show.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/navigation' %>
```

I am fairly new to rails and so can't think how to do this myself and I am resisting the urge to do it in a Javascript way as I know backend output is the correct approach for this.

Any hints or tips are more than welcome. Thank you for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like [simple-navigation](https://github.com/andi/simple-navigation)